# Рекурсивный вариант array_change_key_case

Tags: php

Есть ли вариант функции `array_change_key_case()`, работающий со вложенными массивами?

Comment: в комментах на странице документации приведен код рекурсивного варианта. и даже не один

Comment: @teran, проблем с написанием рекурсивного кода нет. Интересует, есть ли то же самое, только обернутое в функцию, чтобы не пришлось писать этот код. Но, видимо, нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_change_key_case_recursive($arr)
{
    return array_map(function($item){
        if(is_array($item))
            $item = array_change_key_case_recursive($item);
        return $item;
    },array_change_key_case($arr));
}
```